# Cannot start Libreoffice on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: libreoffice

After upgrading Ubuntu to 17.10 I cannot run LibreOffice at all any more.
I get a pop-up window with the text:

"The application cannot be started. LibreOffice user installation could not be processed due to missing access rights. Please ensure that you have sufficient access rights for the following location and restart LibreOffice:

/my/homedir/.config/libreoffice/4
"

This happens with the default version available for Ubuntu 17.10 and it also happens after purging and re-installing and after purging and re-installing version 6.0 from the PPA.

All directories from the path  /my/homedir/.config/libreoffice/4 are owned by my user and my group and have permissions drwxr-xr-x for directories and -rw-rw-r-- for files in them.

So the message LibreOffice shows to me is apparently a lie.

Comment: Have you tried to move the directory out of the way temporarily?  `mv /my/homedir/.config/libreoffice /my/homedir/.config/libreoffice.bak`

Comment: Yes, I completely deleted this directory before trying and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I could solve just removing the libreoffice, after that I've done `#sudo apt-get autoremove -f`, and then `#sudo apt-get update; #sudo apt-get upgrade;` and reinstall the libre! It's solved for me!

Comment: I did this and it did not change anything. As I wrote I even tried to then install the version 6 from the PPA which also did not solve the problem.